# Opening a Cocoa window in MonoMac

Tags: c#, cocoa, mono, nswindowcontroller

I am trying to accomplish the very simple task of opening a new window, but I seem to be completely unable to do so.

I am using MonoMac with monobjc on a Mac. When creating a new monobjc project, a MainMenu.xib is created. I have managed to add controls and binding to this file using the XCode editor. This window is automatically opened when the application is launched.

When I attempt to create a new window, however, I can't make it show up at all. I created a .xib file by right clicking the parent folder of MainMenu.xib, and clicking Add file => Cocoa Window Template. This file can be edited in XCode just a MainMenu.xib.

I then proceeded to create a class inheriting NSWindowController, and I chose this class as the "File's owner" of the window in my .xib file. I have then been able to design the window, and to add outlets and actions to the controller.

But I can't figure out how to open the window. I have tried multiple variations of this:

```
var f = new RegularLoginForm(); //which inherits NSWindowController
f.LoadWindow(); //I have tried without this line
f.ShowWindow(null); // I have also tried sending in the AppDelegate object (which is the controller for MainMenu.xib)
```

But nothing seems to work -- that is, the window never opens. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of how my .xib and it's configuration looks: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1545094/so_nswindowcontroller.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set RegularLoginForm as File's Owner in your Window.xib; but did you also connect the Window outlet from File's Owner to the Window in Interface Builder?

i.e. Right-click on File's Owner in IB, and click-drag the Window outlet to the Window object

Further to that, I tried your code and for me it crashes on the call to

```
f.ShowWindow(null)
```

*[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: sender*

It runs fine if I assign the sender parameter, e.g.

```
f.ShowWindow(this)
```

However, my environment is only MonoMac; no monoobjc (I'm not sure how or why you are using both together?); so YMMV.

Comment: Yes, if I understood you correctly, I've done that too. This is how it looks: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1545094/so_nswindowcontroller.png

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. My "Intellisense" (if such a word applies to MonoDevelop) tells me that the parameter can indeed be null, and throws no exceptions, but I've tried to send in my NSApplication too. What is 'this' in your case? And if it's not too much trouble, perhaps you could send me your working example for me to dissect?

Comment: I'm using the latest MonoMac, and ShowWindow(NSObject sender) clearly throws ArgumentNullException is sender == null. Sender can be anything though, I just tried with new NSObject(IntPtr.Zero) and it worked fine

Comment: Thank you. Your example runs as expected in my environment too, but mine still doesn't. I'll dissect it further when I'm back at work, and come back here with the result.

Comment: So, after experimenting a bit, I now know: a) Even though I only use Monobjc for a single (albeit essential) function, my entire project needs to be a Monobjc project for this function to work. b) In a Monobjc project, I am unable to open new forms. But at least I now know that it is related to Monobjc, and I hope that will help me figure out what to do.

Comment: @ErlendD. Out of interest, what do you need monoobjc for?

Comment: For executing AppleScripts. I have tried using http://applescriptslim.codeplex.com/, but this makes the scripts behave differently, for some reason (in addition to being slow, as it compiles the scripts). If there are any other options, I'll be willing to try anything now.