# Creating NSWindow programmatically in Mono using MonoMac.dll Ref

Tags: mono, nswindow, monomac

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351006/monomac-project-calling-assembly-reflectiononlyload-in-mono-project) is because I am trying two routes to the same conclusion.

I have an application that is written in c# and I am now porting to the mac. This is working using Mono.

I am using a Mac Mini Mid 2011 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
osx 10.8.2
IDE
Xamarin Studio
Version 4.0.4 (build 2)
Installation UUID: 0df3cd36-37ed-4451-8ca7-370ec8220237
Mono 2.10.11 (mono-2-10/2baeee2)
GTK 2.24.14
GTK# (2.12.0.0)
Package version: 210110000
Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 4.6 (2066)
Build 4H127

I need a simple web view for my Gui as we are changing to a html5 Frontend.
Mono does not have a web browser for Mac that can be used. 
MonoMac does so I am trying to add the MonoMac.dll to a mono project.

```
    lock(typeof(Frontend2))
{
  NSApplication.Init();
}
    RectangleF rec = new RectangleF(0,0,500,500);
WebView web = new WebView(rec, "A", "B");

NSWindow win = new NSWindow(rec, NSWindowStyle.Resizable,           NSBackingStore.Buffered,false);
    NSApplication.SharedApplication.AddWindowsItem(win, "Hello",false);
```

The application runs and compiles unfortunately I am unable to make the NSWindow appear.
I understand in a MonoMac project there is a xib file and things.
So I was just wondering if anyone knew a way to make it work or if it is even possible to do what I am doing.
Thank you for any feed back.
Paul

Comment: See if this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753166/opening-a-cocoa-window-in-monomac/14755923#14755923 question and answer helps you